# pictorial representation of pre and post ordering for edge types

Tags: depth-first-search

I am reading chapter 3 **Decomposition of Graphs** of *Algorithms* by Dasgupta, Papadimitriou & Vazirani and they show a pictorial representation of pre and post numbers with brackets for tree, forward, back and cross edges. I have pasted the image of the area I am unclear on.

I am assuming that **u** is the node/vertex we see first and then we see **v** later. Comparing to the 2nd image showing the definitions on a graph, I am taking **u** as node **A**.

What I don't get is the order for the other 2 back and cross edges. What I have is

- `u v u v` for back edge.
- `u u v v` for cross edge.

Essentially the order is flipped with `u` and `v` in what the textbook has. Could someone clarify why this is the case with the image below.

[image: Edge types]

[image: Edge definitions]

I read [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/98869/understanding-the-ordering-of-the-four-types-of-edges-in-dfs) but I came out more confused with the explanation.

Surprisingly I was able to correctly identify the pre and post numbers in this figure in the textbook. It is the letters `u` and `v` that have me confused.

[image]

Comment: I did both. Sorry for the delay. I also have a follow up on the exercise portion of your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I am assuming that $u$ is the node/vertex we see first and then we see $v$ later." That is a wrong assumption, which makes [that summarizing table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPN1Z.png) unintelligible.

The right assumption consists of two parts.

- We are given a directed graph that contains $(u,v)$, the edge from $u$ to $v$.
- We have just completed one depth first search (DFS) on that graph, which has discovered both $u$ and $v$.

Given the assumption above, that table lists the correspondence between the "pre/post ordering for $u$ and $v$", and the "edge type" of $(u,v)$. Please note that I rephrase "pre/post ordering for $(u,v)$" as in the table to "pre/post ordering for $u$ and $v$", since the meaning of "$(u,v)$", the edge from $u$ to $v$ does not fit the former phrase exactly.

- The first row, "$\stackrel{[}{u}\,\stackrel{[}{v}\,\stackrel{]}{v}\,\stackrel{]}{u}\ $ Tree/forward" says that $u$'s discovery time and departure time enclose $v$'s discovery time and departure iff $(u,v)$ is a tree edge or a forward edge. $u$ is visited first in this case.
- The second row, "$\stackrel{[}{v}\,\stackrel{[}{u}\,\stackrel{]}{u}\,\stackrel{]}{v}\ $ Back" says that $v$'s discovery time and departure time enclose $u$'s discovery time and departure time iff $(u,v)$ is a back edge. $v$ is visited first in this case.
- The third row, "$\stackrel{[}{v}\,\stackrel{]}{v}\,\stackrel{[}{u}\,\stackrel{]}{u}\ $ Cross" says that $v$'s discovery time and departure time are before $u$'s discovery time and departure time iff $(u,v)$ is a cross edge. $v$ is visited first in this case.

Neither do we assume $u$ is visited first nor do we assume $v$ is visited first. The node that is visited first on each row of that table is, of course, the node that appears first from the left on that row.

---

**Exercise** (as given in the book). With the same assumption, "do you see why no other orderings are possible?" For example, why is "$\stackrel{[}{v}\,\stackrel{[}{u}\,\stackrel{]}{v}\,\stackrel{]}{u}$" not possible? why is "$\stackrel{[}{u}\,\stackrel{]}{u}\,\stackrel{[}{v}\,\stackrel{]}{v}$" not possible?

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the order is not set. I should always consider that the edge begins at $u$ and ends at $v$. Doing so makes the ordering in the table sensible.

Comment: I think the answer the exercise/your question has two parts. One, there aren't other possibilities of edges in the same connected component of a directed graph. Second, we can't have those orderings unless we are considering the pre and post numbers of different/distinct connected components. Are both parts correct?

Comment: @heretoinfinity, it looks like you are on the right track. For a directed graph, the notion of "connected component" is usually not defined. For example, it is not defined in the book hereof. Instead, we usually talk about "strongly connected component".

Comment: Following up on the exercise and my response. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Probably not.  You could also take a look at the end of [the source of my post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/revisions/312e2af1-6fbc-417c-a9be-254e0fc45596/view-source), which answers the exercise.